# undefined reference to `test' when linking shared object

Tags: c, linker, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm studying a tutorial how to link shared objects in C

Here's my make file

```
test: glenn.c libhala.so
    gcc glenn.c -L. -o test

libhala.so: hala.o
    gcc -shared hala.o -o libhala.so

hala.o: hala.c hala.h
    gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic hala.c

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm *.so
    rm test
```

hala.h

```
#ifndef HALA
#define HALA

extern void test(char*);
#endif
```

hala.c

```
#include "hala.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern void test(char* s)
{

    printf("%s", s);
}
```

glenn.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hala.h"

int main()
{
    test("Hello There!");
    return 0;
}
```

This stocks me up. Help me please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `-lhaha` when you link `glenn.c`.

```
gcc glenn.c -L. -lhala -o test
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `-lhala` while compiling `glenn.c`, so update makefile as

```
test: glenn.c libhala.so
    gcc glenn.c -L. -lhala -o test
```

Comment: THanks. This worked on me.

i have another question. if i use

test: glenn.c libhala.so
    gcc glenn.c libhala.so -o test

this also works on me. are they same or not?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw, more preferred way is having `-lhala`.